# How to make UITableViewCell show the whole height of UICollectionView inside it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I've UITableView and inside one of it's cells I've added UICollectionView programmatically

but after showing the UICollectionView the UITableViewCell only shows the first row of UICollectionView[image: as this picture]

and this is my code for UITableView :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}


  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
        let collectionViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell
        collectionViewCell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#eeeeee")

        return collectionViewCell
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and this is my UITableView custom Cell which include UICollectionView :

```
      private class collectionViewCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

private let reuseableCell = "CellId"

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseableCell)
    setupViews()

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}


let imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return collectionView
}()


func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    addSubview(imagesCollectionView)

    imagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    imagesCollectionView.delegate = self
    imagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#eeeeee")
    imagesCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseableCell)

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imagesCollectionView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imagesCollectionView]))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = imagesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseableCell, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 200) // 68
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

so any help ?

Comment: Is content inside your collection view changes dynamically?

Comment: it will be images from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionView will not grow automatically according to its content and so the table cell.

You will have to set height constraint for your UICollectionView and change the constraint constant as per the content height. Then, if you have constraints set for edges of UICollectionView equal to cell's content view then cell will also adjust the height automatically.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Please add below heightForRowAt method and estimatedRowHeight and check it

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 //Any Value you want
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Welcome and enjoy coding